# Being DM for a DND 5E club

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

I'm new to this website, so forgive me if this question has been asked a billion times, but I'm kind of a predicament here. I haven't played either DND or PF in a little less than 2 years, and I'm being asked to DM for an up and running club on my college's campus. While, at worst, I'm going to at least end up winging it and hopefully not failing, I haven't DMed for anything at all in a long time. To make matters worse, it's DND, not PF, which is what I have experience DMing. Any tips, advice? I'm also looking for a bit of a rundown here, since a DND 5E book is a little less than $27 on Amazon, and I'm hesitant to spend the money without knowing what I'm getting into.

Thanks for helping a noob out!

Comment: Welcome to the RPG.SE!  Glad to have you post a question.  Please take the [tour] to see how this site differs from some other sites, and how our question and answer format works.  Happy Gaming! :-)

Comment: Welcome.  Here on RPG.SE we do specific questions with specific answers - this is more a general request for tips.  Try focusing in on your exact problem.  An overview of the differences between PF and 5e is here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/differences-between-5th-edition-dd-and-pathfinder. You have at least 3-4 problems mixed into this question (haven't GMed in a long time, am GMing a new system for the first time, want to know how 5e differs from PF, running a game in a club environment). Some have already been asked/answered here as a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

If the club wants you to DM, and you have not played 5e yet, I suggest that your response be as follows:

"I need to play a few raids/missions first so that I can get a feel to how 5e differs from PF."

You are being put on the spot, and you don't have to put up with that.  If your being DM is the precondition to you getting to join, you are being jerked around.

**Recommendation**: play a few times so that you get used to the rules.

Download [the Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/BasicRules_Playerv3.4_PF.pdf) and the [Basic DM rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMBasicRules_NoBackground.pdf) from the Wizards of the Coast site, they are free, so that you can be familiar with the basics before you try to run a game.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the D&D 5e rules [are out for free](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules).
This will surely solve the investment issue, since you can legally play the game without spending a dime, buying (into) the game only if you feel you want to support it or if you want more options.

Second, I have no idea how much you've played editions other than 3.PF, but the ruleset is pretty much guaranteed to be really different from what you were used to, much more than 3.5e was different from 3e or from PF.
Take your time to carefully read the rules and try to let go of all the rules you were used to, for they will rarely apply. Actually, the hiatus you took might prove beneficial since it helps you rebuild around the new rules without having the old ones clog your mind.