# What is the best way to learn 5E coming from 3.5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

I have been playing 3.5E for the past 7 years. My group wants to try 5th edition. What is the best way to get started for me and my group? What are the major differences between 5E and 3.5E that we should keep in mind? Thanks!

Comment: Also maybe of use and related (as 3.5 and Pathfinder are very similar): [Pathfinder compared to 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/differences-between-5th-edition-dd-and-pathfinder)

Comment: I added an answer specifically for gotchas when transitioning from 3.5/Pathfinder to the linked duplicate question, maybe it will be of use.