# Differences between 5e and 3.5e

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, edition-comparison

I'm thinking about playing a game of 3.5e with some friends, but I've only played/DM'd 5e games. So, what's the primary differences between the two, just so I'm not jumping in completely haplessly?

This question is a bit broad, but I've done not much about 3.5e ever.

Comment: Related in the exact opposite perspective (dupe?): [For seasoned 3.X players and DMs, what is the "what's new" summary for 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45835/52137)